# Changing Server Settings and Adding New Files Are Not Detected in Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I was trying to learn how to use servlet by following the tutorial in this page:

https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html

When I reached **2.6  STEP 5: Develop and Deploy a WebApp**, I was told to restart tomcat so that it'll load the directory I just made. However, the changes I made was not loaded, the assigned port is still 8080 even though I assigned it to 9999 and the **hello** directory was not found. Here are the messages when I issued startup.bat:

```
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.21 using APR version 1.6.5.
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018)
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 494 ms
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\Tomcat 2\webapps\docs
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [146] milliseconds.
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\Tomcat 2\webapps\examples
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\Tomcat 2\webapps\host-manager
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\Tomcat 2\webapps\manager
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\Tomcat 2\webapps\ROOT
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 26, 2019 5:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1092 ms
```

As you can see, the **hello** directory was not deployed. So, what is exactly happening here?

Comment: You didn't edit `server.xml`. Or not the right one.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, I had it edited, the one in the conf directory

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that when I issued the startup & shutdown command that there was an information in the console which looked like this:

```
Using CLASSPATH: "G:\Learning\tomcat9\bin\bootstrap.jar;G:\Learning\tomcat9\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

It seemed that my classpath was pointing to the wrong path. I deleted CATALINA_HOME in the environment variable settings, and now it is working fine.